# System Tray Notiifications show up when running the project in the debug mode in IDE [VS2017] but not in compiled exe in C# project

Tags: c#, events, system-tray, notifyicon

I have multiple connected apps, one of which fires events and another runs in the system tray and displays notifications for those events. It used to work properly, but after making a change related to threading in one of the applications, it stopped working. The method is correctly called [I put a messagebox in that event], and in fact, the first time the event is fired after starting the apps, I get a small disturbance on the screen near the system tray, which goes away immediately. Subsequent events evoke no response. I have also tried  using the Synchronization Context [Post method] to see if the situation was resolved, but there is no difference. Usually, with threading issues, the synchronization context solves it. I found the following question on Stack overflow, but it did not help either
[System tray icon working in debug but not release mode, in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215492/system-tray-icon-working-in-debug-but-not-release-mode-in-qt). 
Please help.

Comment: Difficult to help you without any code. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ahhh i know what that is!!!!... just kidding. A description just want be enough... Who knows what the problem is with the code! The only way we could know is if we see the code. The assumption is you didn't post it because it was complicated or overly verbose, that's where you create a small verifiable example so we can test it

Comment: `after making a change related to threading in one of the applications, it stopped working` rollback a change then

Comment: Thanks!. Before posting the code, I tried out various combinations of code, including rolling back the change.Nothing worked on my machine. However, it works perfectly on another machine. So it seems something is wrong with my installation of VS2017. Now I have to find out what is wrong with my VS2017

Comment: Also, I created an installer on the other machine and installed on my machine, but the same problem persists [No notifications are shown].